# opening a page within a frame onclicking a button

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have divided the page into two halves, on the top layer i have a profile page(myprofile.jsp) with a button saying edit profile, on clicking the button i want the editprofile.jsp to open in the below frame.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="I want to load that page in the below frame"><span class="fa fa-gear"></span> Request CLI </button>  
                        </div><!--/col-->
                    </div><!--/row-->
              </div><!--/panel-body-->
          </div><!--/panel-->



    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Lower post panel -->
  <div class="col-md-14">

      <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="spinner" style="display:none" class="spinner">
  <img id="loading-image" src="img/spinner.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
 <iframe name="result"  id="result" frameborder="0" class="resultframe" onload="removeLoad()"></iframe>

              </div><!--/panel-body-->
          </div><!--/panel-->



    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: So.. what is the problem? Have you tried anything? Why not just an `a` tag? Than you can do `<a href="editprofile.jsp" target="result">Edit profile</a>`

Comment: i have done that already.. i want it to open on button click..

Comment: Style the `a` tag as a `button`?

Comment: using an <a> tag i know how to do it, the problem is on clicking a button i want to open a page.. when i tried it opened separately i want it to open under a particular frame

Comment: That is why you have to add `target="result"` to your `a` tag so it will open in your frame called `result`.

Comment: i dont want it in an <a> tag.. i want it in a button with javascript

Comment: Alright.. well, you got your answer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following code in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openEditProfile() {
        var frm = document.getElementById('result');
        frm.src = 'editprofile.jsp';
    }
</script>
```

Then set the onclick of the button to

```
onclick="openEditProfile()"
```